# Jobs I can get with an AI master degree

Tags: computer-science

I am asking this question again because it was closed for the wrong reason. I am not asking for a specific advice on what I should do after graduating. I just want to know from people who already work what are thy doing, out of curiosity.

Next year I will get my master degree in computer science, with specialization in artificial intelligence. The exams I am taking regard fields like machine learning, deep learning, compuitational intelligence, advanced database systems, computer vision, big data. I know the kind of jobs that my bachelor degree (computer science) allows me to get, but I have no idea about which positions I can best suit in with my master degree background. I looked on the internet and wasn't satisfied with the answers I found. That's why I'm writing this post: to reach people who have a degree in AI and ask them: what do you do specifically?

Comment: Did you ask your university? Presumably they offer a master's program since there is some demand in the workplace and they should have some ideas where past graduates ended up? If their answer is "we have no idea", perhaps you should look for a different program.

Answer (score 2):

You should be in contact with your academic department about current jobs that uses your degree. However, if they are not particularly up-to-date with current market trends, they may give you useless answers.

As someone who is casually diving into AI/ML/Big Data and all this stuff, one field jumps out. Robotics Process Automation (RPA).

Since you're at a masters level, you should have no problem digging up contemporary research papers (big hint: use your university academic library database and look for papers). Get a bunch of industry wide research papers on this subject (Robotics Process Automation) and a sub-set of Data Mining called Process Mining. These two topics will get you started on what's happening in this industry and let you position yourself to get into these jobs.